# Separation of string into multiple string value

Tags: php

I have a string with `underscores(_)`. What I want is to get the string value after the first underscore and considered as the first string value and the second string value will be the whole string after the underscore of the first string value using `php`.

Example:

```
$string = "Makes_me_wonder";
```

Result I want:

```
$str1 = "me";
$str2 = "wonder";
```

Another variable I am having:

```
$string = "I_wont_gohome_withoutyou";
```

Result should be:

```
$str1 = "wont";
$str2 = "gohome_withoutyou";
```

Another one:

```
$string = 'Never_gonna_leave_this_bed";
```

Output i want:-

```
$str1 = "gonna_leave"; 
$str2 = "this_bed";
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: oh sorry! I will edit it. Thanks!!

Comment: What if it is only `Makes_me`? Will your string will have always more than 2 underscores?

Comment: @Thamilan no it won't happen.

Comment: @Anant yours is a good answer. How can I mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is like this:-

```
<?php
function getfinal_result($string){
    $final_data = explode('_',$string,2)[1]; // explode with first occurrence of _ and leave first word
    if(substr_count($final_data,'_')>2){ // now check  _ remains  is greater that 2
        $first_data = substr($final_data , 0, strpos($final_data , '_', strpos($final_data , '_')+1)); // find the string comes after second _
        $second_data = str_replace($first_data.'_','',$final_data); // get the string before the second _
        $last_data = Array($first_data,$second_data); // assign them to final data
    }else{
        $last_data = explode('_',$final_data,2); // directly explode with first occurance of _
    }
    return $last_data; // return final data

}
$first_data = getfinal_result('Makes_me_wonder');
$second_data = getfinal_result('I_wont_gohome_withoutyou');
$third_data = getfinal_result('Never_gonna_leave_this_bed');

echo "<pre/>";print_r($first_data);
echo "<pre/>";print_r($second_data);
echo "<pre/>";print_r($third_data);
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/593240

Comment: Oh! I forgot. There is another case that will surely happen. I edited my question.

Comment: @PHPNoob  i updated my answer. Please check and if correct then mark and up-vote the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with 3rd parameter - *limit*:

[DEMO](https://eval.in/593192)

```
$string = "I_wont_gohome_withoutyou";

$arr = explode("_",$string,3);

$str1 = $arr[1];   //wont
$str2 = $arr[2];   //gohome_withoutyou
```

Provided that you have two or more `_` in a word strictly. If it is so, there needs a work around too.

Comment: Oh! I forgot. There is another case that will surely happen. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
function explode($string)
{
    $delimiter = '_';
    return explode($delimiter, explode($delimiter, $string, 2)[1], 2);
}

$string = "Makes_me_wonder";
$strings = explode($string);
echo $strings[0]; //me
echo $strings[1]; //wonder

$string = "I_wont_gohome_withoutyou";
$strings = explode($string);
echo $strings[0]; //wont
echo $strings[1]; //gohome_withoutyou
```

Comment: your solution doesn't covers op's second case

Comment: Oh! I forgot. There is another case that will surely happen. I edited my question.

Comment: Oh! I forgot. There is another case that will surely happen. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods but here's one of them.

```
$pos1 = strpos($string, '_');
$pos2 = strpos($string, '_', $pos1 + 1);
$str1 = substr($string, $pos1 + 1, $pos2 - $pos1 - 1);
$str2 = substr($string, $pos2 + 1);
```

This assumes that there are at least 2 underscores in the string.

Comment: Oh! I forgot. There is another case that will surely happen. I edited my question.

Comment: @PHPNoob That second case doesn't make sense. You sure it's correct?

Comment: yes I am sure it's correct it sometimes appear a string like that.